# We define ⌊α⌋= max{n | n ≤ α} and α mod 1 = α−⌊α⌋ and let α ∈ R be irrational.

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

My current thought, since α is irrational, α mod 1 is a positive irrational number, so does ka. We know α mod 1 must be smaller than 1. However, I don't know how to finish the proof rigorously.

Comment: This is not true.  Take $n=1$.  Are you missing an $n$-hypothesis or something?

Comment: It's certainly true for $n = 1$.  After all, $\alpha$ mod 1 is in $[0,1]$.